# Checking source files (text files) for a certain structure in C#

Tags: c#

Below I have an example of some text (in this case it's C source code, could be any structured text honestly). I am trying to read a couple files, with variable length and different structures and figure out if for example, after every `#define` an `#include "test.h"` is present.

The same case can apply to both, within and out of the preprocessor directives (`#if, #ifdef, #ifndef, #endif`). It is also allowed that a `#include "test.h"` appears after a `#endif`, if the proper `#define` was within the `if-directive` prior to this.

A few side notes:

I extract the text from the file, do some actions such as removing comments, irrelevant lines, empty lines and soon and return the file as a `string[]`. This makes it fairly easy to iterate and jump back and forth between the lines `SourceCode[i]`

I have attempted to implement a solution with a few different approaches, and never managed to fully hit the nail.

My first attempt consisted of an endless amount of if-else-statements and while-loops, for every imaginable path in the logic. This ended up being so hard to maintain, confusing and to hard keep control upon.

Next, I've tried implementing a state machine, to keep track of where I am in the text file, jumping to different states as needed. I couldn't find a perfect solution.

Another attempt I've tried was using a stack, pushing a `#define` to the stack, checking what it was, pushing the next line to the stack, checking if it is `#include`, if not then return an error. This also, of course, is a bit more complicated as soon as I have directives, as one #include is sufficient for multiple `#defines`.

I've looked into parsers (mainly Antlr), realizing that this is possibly way too overkill for such a problem, also considering I have absolutely no clue about parsers and would need to make my own grammar.

> Source code example

```
// directives
#if (TEST == true)
    #define START_TEST_1
    #include "test.h"
  #else
    #define START_TEST_2
    #include "test.h"
#endif

#if (TEST == true)
    #define STOP_TEST_1
  #else
    #define STOP_TEST_2
#endif
#include "test.h"

// no directives
#define START_TEST_3
#include "test.h"

#define STOP_TEST_3
#include "test.h"
```

Does anyone have some general tips and can maybe point me in a specific direction. What would be a suitable solution to this problem?

**Edit: @jdweng**

```
    dt.Columns.Add("Next #elif State", typeof(int));

    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 12, DEFINE_STATE.FOUND_ELIF, 13, 0, 2, 7, 12, 10, ERROR.NO_ERROR, ACTION.NONE });
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 13, DEFINE_STATE.FOUND_DEFINE_IN_ELIF, -1, 14, 2, 7, 12, 10, ERROR.DEFINE_FOLLOWED_BY_DEFINE, ACTION.SET_DEFINE_ELIF_LINE_NUMBER });
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 14, DEFINE_STATE.FOUND_INCLUDE_IN_ELIF, 13, 0, 2, 7, 12, 10, ERROR.NO_ERROR, ACTION.RESET_DEFINE_ELIF_LINE_NUMBER });
```

I added a check to see if elif_level is == 0, if so, then proceed as usual, removing the level of if-nest. Otherwise I remove elif_level and then the if-nest level.

Do the above rows look correct? I am thinking of either adding a bool variable to states that is set to true if elif is found, and later when I find an #endif I can pop all states that have elif set to true.

Comment: Do you want a `C` or a `C#` solution? If you decided for one, please remove the other tag.

Comment: @hellow Whoops, my bad, think I clicked on one of the suggested tags.

Comment: @mjwills The file will compile, I am just trying to implement a way of seeing if certain requirements are not met, such as an #include missing where it should be according to a specific requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been parsing text files like this for over 40 years.  This is a complicate logic issue so with any complicated logic issue I would use a State Machine.  First I drew a state diagram

[image]

Then I wrote code to implement the state table

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public enum DEFINE_STATE
    {
        SPECIAL = -4,  //define followed by IF
        NONE = -3,
        INVALID = -2, //Compile will give error, cannot occur
        ERROR = -1,
        DO_NOT_CARE = 0,
        START = 1,
        FOUND_IF = 2,
        FOUND_DEFINE_IN_IF = 3,
        FOUND_DEFINE_NOT_IN_IF = 4,
        FOUND_INCLUDE_IN_IF = 5,
        FOUND_ELSE = 6,
        FOUND_DEFINE_IN_ELSE = 7,
        FOUND_INCLUDE_IN_ELSE = 8,
        FOUND_INCLUDE_NOT_IN_IF = 9,
        FOUND_END_IF = 10,
        RETURN = 11,
        FOUND_ELIF = 12,
        FOUND_DEFINE_IN_ELIF = 13,
        FOUND_INCLUDE_IN_ELIF = 14,
    }
    public enum ERROR
    {
        NO_ERROR,
        DEFINE_FOLLOWED_BY_DEFINE,
        DEFINE_FOLLOWED_BY_DEFINE_OR_IF
    }
    public enum TABLE_COLUMN
    {
        STATE = 0,
        DESCRIPTION = 1,
        DEFINE,
        INCLUDE,
        IF,
        ELSE,
        ELIF,
        END_IF,
        ERROR,
        ACTION
    }

    public enum ACTION
    {
        NONE,
        RESET_DEFINE_LINE_NUMBER,
        RESET_DEFINE_IF_LINE_NUMBER,
        RESET_DEFINE_ELSE_LINE_NUMBER,
        RESET_DEFINE_ELIF_LINE_NUMBER,
        SET_DEFINE_LINE_NUMBER,
        SET_DEFINE_IF_LINE_NUMBER,
        SET_DEFINE_ELSE_LINE_NUMBER,
        SET_DEFINE_ELIF_LINE_NUMBER,
    }
    public class State_Variables
    {
        public int define_Line_Number = 0;
        public int define_If_Line_Number = 0;
        public int define_Else_Line_Number = 0;
        public int define_Elif_Line_Number = 0;
        public int return_end_level = 0;
        public DEFINE_STATE state = DEFINE_STATE.START;
        public DataRow row { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pattern = "#include\\s+\"test.h\"";
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string input = "";

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("State", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(DEFINE_STATE));
            dt.Columns.Add("Next Define State", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Next Include State", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Next IF State", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Next Else State", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Next ELIF State", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Next ENDIF State", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Error Number", typeof(ERROR));
            dt.Columns.Add("Action", typeof(ACTION));

            //0 do not care
            //-1 error
            //-2 invalid
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, DEFINE_STATE.START, 4, 0, 2, -2, -2, -2, ERROR.NO_ERROR, ACTION.NONE });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, DEFINE_STATE.FOUND_IF, 3, 0, 2, 6, 12, 10, ERROR.NO_ERROR, ACTION.NONE });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, DEFINE_STATE.FOUND_DEFINE_IN_IF, -1, 5, 2, 6, 12, 10, ERROR.DEFINE_FOLLOWED_BY_DEFINE, ACTION.SET_DEFINE_IF_LINE_NUMBER });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, DEFINE_STATE.FOUND_DEFINE_NOT_IN_IF, -1, 9, -4, -2, -2, -2, ERROR.DEFINE_FOLLOWED_BY_DEFINE, ACTION.SET_DEFINE_LINE_NUMBER });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, DEFINE_STATE.FOUND_INCLUDE_IN_IF, 3, 0, 2, 6, 12, 10, ERROR.NO_ERROR, ACTION.RESET_DEFINE_IF_LINE_NUMBER });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 6, DEFINE_STATE.FOUND_ELSE, 7, 0, 2, -2, -2, 10, ERROR.NO_ERROR, ACTION.NONE });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 7, DEFINE_STATE.FOUND_DEFINE_IN_ELSE, -1, 8, 2, -2, -2, 10, ERROR.DEFINE_FOLLOWED_BY_DEFINE, ACTION.SET_DEFINE_ELSE_LINE_NUMBER });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 8, DEFINE_STATE.FOUND_INCLUDE_IN_ELSE, 7, 0, 2, -2, -2, 10, ERROR.NO_ERROR, ACTION.RESET_DEFINE_ELSE_LINE_NUMBER });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 9, DEFINE_STATE.FOUND_INCLUDE_NOT_IN_IF, 4, 0, 2, -2, -2, -2, ERROR.NO_ERROR, ACTION.RESET_DEFINE_LINE_NUMBER });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 10, DEFINE_STATE.FOUND_END_IF, 11, 1, 2, -2, -2, -2, ERROR.NO_ERROR, ACTION.NONE });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 11, DEFINE_STATE.RETURN, -2, -2, 2, -2, -2, -2, ERROR.NO_ERROR, ACTION.NONE });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 12, DEFINE_STATE.FOUND_ELIF, 13, 0, 2, -2, 12, 10, ERROR.NO_ERROR, ACTION.NONE });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 13, DEFINE_STATE.FOUND_DEFINE_IN_ELIF, -1, 14, 2, -2, 12, 10, ERROR.DEFINE_FOLLOWED_BY_DEFINE, ACTION.SET_DEFINE_ELIF_LINE_NUMBER });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 14, DEFINE_STATE.FOUND_INCLUDE_IN_ELIF, 13, 0, 2, 7, 12, 10, ERROR.NO_ERROR, ACTION.RESET_DEFINE_ELIF_LINE_NUMBER });

            int level = 0;
            List<State_Variables> states = new List<State_Variables>();
            State_Variables newState = new State_Variables();
            states.Add(newState);

            DEFINE_STATE nextState = DEFINE_STATE.START;
            ACTION action = ACTION.NONE;
            int line_number = 0;

            while ((input = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line_number++;

                input = input.Trim();
                if (input.StartsWith("//")) continue;  //ignore comments
                if (input.Length == 0) continue;

                 Boolean returnFromIF = false;
                 Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

                //test if end if is followed by include
                if (states[level].state == DEFINE_STATE.FOUND_END_IF)
                {
                    int return_end_level = 0;  
                    do
                    {
                        if (!match.Success)
                        {


                            int define_If_Line_Number = states[level].define_If_Line_Number;
                            int define_Else_Line_Number = states[level].define_Else_Line_Number;
                            int define_Elif_Line_Number = states[level].define_Elif_Line_Number;

                            if (define_If_Line_Number != 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Define in IF at line {0} does not have and include", define_If_Line_Number.ToString());
                            }

                            if (define_Else_Line_Number != 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Define in ELSE at line {0} does not have and include", define_Else_Line_Number.ToString());
                            }

                            if (define_Elif_Line_Number != 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Define in ELSE at line {0} does not have and include", define_Else_Line_Number.ToString());
                            }

                        }
                        return_end_level = states[level].return_end_level;
                        states.RemoveAt(level--);
                    } while (level > return_end_level);

                    returnFromIF = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    states[level].row = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>((int)TABLE_COLUMN.STATE) == (int)states[level].state).FirstOrDefault();
                }

                nextState = DEFINE_STATE.NONE;

                //check if defines are terminated with include

                if (input.Contains("#define"))
                {
                    nextState = (DEFINE_STATE)states[level].row.Field<int>((int)TABLE_COLUMN.DEFINE);

                }
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    if (returnFromIF)
                    {
                        nextState = states[level].state;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nextState = (DEFINE_STATE)states[level].row.Field<int>((int)TABLE_COLUMN.INCLUDE);
                    }
                }
                if (input.Contains("#if"))
                {
                    nextState = (DEFINE_STATE)states[level].row.Field<int>((int)TABLE_COLUMN.IF);
                    states.Add(new State_Variables());
                    level++;
                    states[level].return_end_level = level - 1;
                }
                if (input.Contains("#else"))
                {
                    nextState = (DEFINE_STATE)states[level].row.Field<int>((int)TABLE_COLUMN.ELSE);
                }
                if (input.Contains("#elif"))
                {
                    nextState = (DEFINE_STATE)states[level].row.Field<int>((int)TABLE_COLUMN.ELIF);
                    states.Add(new State_Variables());
                    level++;
                    states[level].return_end_level = states[level - 1].return_end_level;
                }
                if (input.Contains("#endif"))
                {
                    nextState = (DEFINE_STATE)states[level].row.Field<int>((int)TABLE_COLUMN.END_IF);
                }

                if ((nextState != DEFINE_STATE.ERROR) && (nextState != DEFINE_STATE.DO_NOT_CARE) && (nextState != DEFINE_STATE.NONE))
                {
                    states[level].state = nextState;
                }

                switch (nextState)
                {
                    case   DEFINE_STATE.DO_NOT_CARE:
                        //stay at current state
                        break;
                    case DEFINE_STATE.NONE:  //stay at current state
                        Console.WriteLine("Did not find state at line {0}", line_number);
                        break;

                    case DEFINE_STATE.INVALID:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid IF/ELSE/END_IF at line {0}", line_number);
                        break;

                    case DEFINE_STATE.ERROR:
                        action = states[level].row.Field<ACTION>((int)TABLE_COLUMN.ACTION);

                        switch (action)
                        {
                            case ACTION.SET_DEFINE_LINE_NUMBER:
                                Console.WriteLine("Define followed by Define at line {0}", states[level].define_Line_Number.ToString());
                                states[level].define_Line_Number = line_number;
                                break;

                            case ACTION.SET_DEFINE_IF_LINE_NUMBER:
                                Console.WriteLine("Define in IF followed by Define by at line {0}", states[level].define_If_Line_Number.ToString());
                                states[level].define_If_Line_Number = line_number;
                                break;

                            case ACTION.SET_DEFINE_ELSE_LINE_NUMBER:
                                Console.WriteLine("Define in ELSE followed by Define at line {0}", states[level].define_Else_Line_Number.ToString());
                                states[level].define_Else_Line_Number = line_number;
                                break;
                            case ACTION.SET_DEFINE_ELIF_LINE_NUMBER :
                                Console.WriteLine("Define in ELIF followed by Define at line {0}", states[level].define_Elif_Line_Number.ToString());
                                states[level].define_Elif_Line_Number = line_number;
                                break;
                        }
                        break;

                    case DEFINE_STATE.SPECIAL:
                        Console.WriteLine("Define followed IF at line {0}", states[level].define_Line_Number.ToString());
                        states[level - 1].state = DEFINE_STATE.START;
                        states[level].state = DEFINE_STATE.FOUND_IF;
                        nextState = DEFINE_STATE.FOUND_IF;
                        states[level].row = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<DEFINE_STATE>((int)TABLE_COLUMN.STATE) == nextState).FirstOrDefault();
                        break;

                    default:
                        states[level].row = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<DEFINE_STATE>((int)TABLE_COLUMN.STATE) == nextState).FirstOrDefault();
                        action = states[level].row.Field<ACTION>((int)TABLE_COLUMN.ACTION);

                        switch (action)
                        {
                            case ACTION.RESET_DEFINE_LINE_NUMBER:
                                states[level].define_Line_Number = 0;
                                break;

                            case ACTION.RESET_DEFINE_IF_LINE_NUMBER:
                                states[level].define_If_Line_Number = 0;
                                break;

                            case ACTION.RESET_DEFINE_ELSE_LINE_NUMBER:
                                states[level].define_Else_Line_Number = 0;
                                break;

                           case ACTION.RESET_DEFINE_ELIF_LINE_NUMBER:
                                states[level].define_Elif_Line_Number = 0;
                                break;

                            case ACTION.SET_DEFINE_LINE_NUMBER:
                                states[level].define_Line_Number = line_number;
                                break;

                            case ACTION.SET_DEFINE_IF_LINE_NUMBER:
                                states[level].define_If_Line_Number = line_number;
                                break;

                            case ACTION.SET_DEFINE_ELSE_LINE_NUMBER:
                                states[level].define_Else_Line_Number = line_number;
                                break;
                            case ACTION.SET_DEFINE_ELIF_LINE_NUMBER:
                                states[level].define_Elif_Line_Number = line_number;
                                break;
                        }
                        states[level].state = nextState;

                        break;
                }

            }

            //final checks
            int define_Line_Number = states[level].define_Line_Number;

            if (define_Line_Number != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Define at line {0} does not have and include", define_Line_Number.ToString());
            }
            if (level != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Did not close all IFs with End_If");
            }


            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very thankful for your answer. I took a look at it and I can see exactly what it does, makes perfect sense, have done something along the lines (way more complicated than it should have been). I only have one issue, is it easy to handle the case when the `#include` appears after an `#if-#endif` construct, where it basically applies to any of the `#define's` within the  `#if-#endif` construct?

Comment: I made a change after my original post to check if a #define is followed by another #define without an "include".  The latest code has three "OR'd" Contains where the original contains only two.

Comment: Sorry, formatting doesn't work in comments, I added an edit to my original thread at the bottom with an example.

Comment: You are making things very complicated.  You can have a #define in the "IF" and then the #include in the Else.  What about the cases where you have an include without a define?  I would just make it a requirement to have both the define and the include together in the IF/ELSE.

Comment: Wish I was making it complicated, the requirement allows for this sort of case sadly.

Comment: You are writing you own custom parser when it gets this complicated.  I worked with YACC (Yet Another Compiler Compiler) long time ago and worked with people from Bell Labs that developed YACC.  Took graduate course with teachers from Bell Labs.  All new K&R who developed YACC.  The question becomes if it is easier to write the grammar or take my code and add additional states.  The hard part is when you have an IF where the IF has an include and the Else doesn't.

Comment: Currently I have no spare time to get into custom parsers (have tried reading up on different parsers and how to get started, found it very complicated). I accepted your answer as the answer as it has helped me immensely already. I had a similar approach, although it didn't work nearly as good as yours. Do you know of an elegant way to take care of the problem where the #include is (or isn't) at EOF, because the loop ends as soon as the EOF is reached, not further action being taken.

Comment: I've posted new solution use a state table.  Code works very well.  Even handles nested IF's.  I made it an error if a DEFINE was followed by an IF without an INCLUDE.  I did a lot of testing, but there still may be errors.

Comment: Having an issue where the case comes that there is an IF-ELSE-ENDIF construct without any defines in it. That's fine, because these could be used for something else, not relevant to this. Problem is that I am getting an error at                     nextState = (DEFINE_STATE)states[level].row.Field<int>((int)TABLE_COLUMN.ELSE); - ArgumentNullException. I can't get to the bottom of this behaviour.

Comment: I took you sample and commented out all the defines and includes and did not get error.  Can you update posting with example of issue.  Also make sure you have latest code because I made a few minor corrections on Saturday.

Comment: I got error.  You need to have an include before the IF.  I will work on solution.

Comment: The solution for the error I got was simple.  The include creates a  DO_NOT_CARE state.  So I simply stay at current state when I get a do not care.  The other solution would be to add another row in the datatable for state zero.

Comment: I added another edit (Edit_2) in my original post. Includes the sample, in case you used something else and some more info from my side.

Comment: I forgot to handle the case where there is real code.  One line change  if ((nextState != DEFINE_STATE.ERROR) && (nextState != DEFINE_STATE.DO_NOT_CARE) && (nextState != DEFINE_STATE.NONE))

Comment: Can't state how much I've learned so far from your help. You've opened doors for me! Thank you very much. I've tried to follow so many "tutorials" on similar approaches, always got me confused.

Comment: Could you please explain the use of `public DataRow row` in the `public class State_Variables`? I don't fully understand the use of it

Comment: I in case you have nested IFs. When you end an IF you need to get back to the old datarow.  Every time you have a nested if you create a new state which is similar to pushing the old state onto a stack.  Then when you exit an IF you have to pop everything off the stack.

Comment: I added another edit_3 in original post. The input sample, 2nd #include being commented out for testing purposes makes the program have a `ArgumentNullException` at line 11 of the file, because `row` as expected cannot be `null`, where as when it isn't commented out it works fine.

I tried debugging to get to the bottom of the issue. I thought that maybe the level variable isn't being properly managed. Played around a bit and couldn't  get a result.

Do I maybe need another STATE? But this state should be covered by SPECIAL?

Comment: I modified the code in case DEFINE_STATE.SPECIAL:  Line 9 is the issue.   Even this is an error we are going to set the state to IF.  The state count was advanced from 0 to 1.  So we also need to fix the next state when we return from the IF so I set the next state for level 0 to START.

Comment: That worked. I also found a really bad mistake on my side, since I tried to implement this in my own way, to see how it actually works. At your `states.RemoveAt(level--);`, I removed the state after I decremented the level, which of course removed the wrong state.

Comment: Also, why can't I treat an `#elif` the same as an `#else`?

Comment: elif is really a nested IF in an else clause.  It would have its own endif.  It would also need to push a state onto the stack.

Comment: But the #elif doesn't need a matching #endif when I look at many examples. It would be different if it was #else-#if

Comment: You are correct.  I check msdn and a elif doesn't require an endif.  The simple case you have will work with the following change : if (input.Contains("#else") || input.Contains("#elif"))).  This will only handle the simple case when there are no additional nested if/else/elif.  The full solution is more complicated because you have to do a push of the stack and then pop the stack when you get the end if.  So you need a count of the number of nested elif so you can pop the stack the correct number of times as well as check the you are not missing any #include.

Comment: Assuming I have to use the same stack: I added 3 more states, 12(found elif), 13(found define), 14(found include), added a new column for elif, drew the diagram for the additional states and filled in the numbers as needed. I also have a level variable for elif, when I find #elif I increment this value, so that when I find an #endif I can remove the correct number from the stack, before I then remove the if-nest level from stack.

Comment: Great, you are learning.  Good exercise for modifying code.  To allow nesting of elif I would add a  variable to the 'state' to indicate the level where the elif was found.  So when you find the endif you can pop the stack the correct number of times.

Comment: I've added some new things that I've added to the solution. Can you see any missing or wrong states? Also, when and how exactly do I push and pop? I've tried sticking to the way you did it, but I think something is foul.

Comment: I updated my code to work with elif.  I had to add new column to every row of the datatable to handle the elif.  Did not do a lot of testing.  See if you can do the testing yourself.  Will support.

Comment: I was on the correct path, minor differences, that's good. Needed to adjust some of the TABLE_COLUMNS values ( for example ELIF->ELSE). This now seems to work. Have stumbled upon issues that #includes are marked as missing an #include. Presumably this is because of not correct RemoveAt for if-elif-endif's. Am currently trying to find the issue. Looking like its either in the #include/#endif check or even before, when we set states[level].return_end_level

Comment: I've found it. At least I hope so, the > sign needs to be a <, otherwise the do-while will almost certainly never be executed more than once and we would never land back at the correct "level".

Answer (score 1):

If the common denominator of all text you want to analyze is a hierarchically structured document, maybe you should start by converting it to that and then do the rest of the analysis on the parsed document and not do both at the same time. Perhaps converting it to an XML-document could be sufficient for your case and then do the analysis using XSLT/XPath (Or LINQ for XDocument if you prefer that). This is basically how other code analysis is performed as well  (Roslyn Code Analyzers with Syntax Trees except much more fancy of course).